# jsPlumb and dynamically added containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Since there's no jsPlumb forum anywhere I hope someone here can help me.

I want to generate this graph from some data I get from a JSON-API, what this API gives me are "devices" with a name and multiple sinks/sources, which I want to display as a list with the device-name in the first row.

So I thought I'd use some JQuery to generate these divs and add the jsPlumb-endpoints I need to the device. Unfortunately I can only get endpoints on existing divs to work but not on my dynamically generated ones. Firebug shows me the error "myOffset is null" in the addEndpoint function and I don't really see anything that's wrong.

I made a fiddle of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2mcD2/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id of an element is invalid, `:` is not allowed in ids.

```
jQuery("#source:foo") // will not work
jQuery("*[id='source:foo']") // will work, but you'll need to modify `jsPlumb` code in order to make it work this way
```

Solution: do not use `:` in ids. `_` and `-` are ok.

Comment: Recently I studied what chars are allowed in CSS selectors. In HTML5 everything (except space) is allowed and could be requested with proper escaping: `jQuery("#source\\:foo")`

Answer (score 3):

there's a jsPlumb group here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jsplumb